# Setting alpha a group of elements in a view in SWIFT

Tags: swift, layout, view, alpha

I've created a layout using the Xcode's Autolayout. I have a number of views with label and imageView inside. Is there any way to change the alpha for labels and imageView without creating outlets for all of them in ViewController in code? 
Could I change the alpha for all the elements inside the view in code, not changing it for the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate through a views subviews and set the alpha that way.

```
for v in view.subviews {
    let view = v as! UIView
    view.alpha = 0
}
```

Another approach is to use an `IBOutletCollection` which you can create in interface builder

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there's lots of ways to handle this.

1. You could set up an `IBOutletCollection` of views who's alpha you want to change. An `IBOutletCollection` is really just an array of view objects that the runtime sets up for you. Beware that the order of the objects in the collection view is not guaranteed.
2. You could set a numeric range of tags on your views (starting with a non-zero value) and then use a for loop and the UIView method `viewWithTag`.
3. You could loop through all of a view's subviews in code and manipulate the view's alpha directly.